# Spock unit test is stuck when parallel stream is used

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, java-8, spock

I am having a weird behavior with Java 8 parallel streams in Spock unit tests.

The following code takes a list of `PlanConfigConstraintValidator` and verifies if all return `true`.

Unit test for this code in Spock is given below. Everything worked fine until I added `.parallel()`. When parallel stream is used, the unit test is stuck and never stops.

If I return only one `Mock(PlanConfigConstraintValidator)`, it works, but not when the size is above one.

I have provided the thread dump also at the bottom.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(PlanConfig planConfig, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return getPlanConfigConstraintValidators().stream().parallel()
            .filter(validator -> shouldValidate(planConfig, validator))
            .allMatch(validator -> isValid(planConfig, context, validator));
}
```

Here is the unit test code

```
def "isValid - all validators return true"() {
    when:
    def validator = Spy(PlanConfigValidator) {
        getPlanConfigConstraintValidators() >> [
                Mock(PlanConfigConstraintValidator),
                Mock(PlanConfigConstraintValidator),
        ]
        shouldValidate(_, _) >> true
        isValid(_, _, _) >> true
    }
    def result = validator.isValid(new PlanConfig(), Mock(ConstraintValidatorContext))

    then:
    result
}
```

Thread Dump

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000026aa000 nid=0x1dd78 in Object.wait() [0x00000000034ac000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076da712d8> (a java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:334)
    - locked <0x000000076da712d8> (a java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateParallel(MatchOps.java:242)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateParallel(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.allMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:454)
```

[image: Thread Dump]

Comment: Are there any long running operations? Or `synchronized` code that is run in parallel?

Comment: It might difficult to explain - I won't be very insightful, but probably you're getting a deadlock somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Opal. As you can see, there are only 3 method calls in the code above: `getPlanConfigConstraintValidators()`, `shouldValidate(planConfig, validator)`, `isValid(planConfig, context, validator)`. And all 3 of them are mocked in my example.

Comment: I may try to reproduce it on tomorrow but hardly believe it will happen :/

Comment: Sure, I know it's hard to believe. And it is getting stuck at the terminal operation `allMatch()`. I have another example, where it is getting stuck at the `collect(toList)` terminal operation.

Comment: The code is written in java 8 or in groovy? Spock is used for testing purpose only? I've also prepared a [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33264056) but I'm unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks @Opal for trying this. Yes, the production code is in Java 8. Unit test is in Spock (1.0-groovy-2.4)

Comment: Ok, will try with Java 8 then.

Comment: Have just updated the project to contain a demo with java 8. Unfortunately can't reproduce it :/

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue today and it *seems* that the issue is related to the implementation of a `Spy` in Spock.

Using `parallelStream()` didn't solve the issue in my case.

For me the discussion [here](http://spock-framework.3207229.n2.nabble.com/Using-thread-pools-in-a-Spock-Spy-d-class-hangs-during-unit-tests-td7574429.html) has been helpful.

I ended up with an anonymous subclass. The example of the OP would look like this with my solution:

```
def "isValid - all validators return true"() {
    when:
    def validator = new PlanConfigValidator() {
       @Override 
       List<PlanConfigConstraintValidator> getPlanConfigConstraintValidators() {
             Arrays.asList(Mock(PlanConfigConstraintValidator),
                Mock(PlanConfigConstraintValidator))
       }

       @Override 
       boolean shouldValidate(_,_) {
            return true
       }

       @Override
       boolean isValid(_,_,_) {
            return true
       }
    } 

    def result = validator.isValid(new PlanConfig(), Mock(ConstraintValidatorContext))

    then:
    result
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this saves lives. Said differently, you can try to replace your Spy by an anonymous class in the Spock test, because apparently Spock's Spy does not properly manage parallel streams.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem and was able to get around it by:

1. Using parallelStream(), instead of stream().parallel()
2. Implementing List like so (in Groovy):

```
    private class NoParallelStreamsList implements List {

        @Delegate
        List delegateList

        @Override
        Stream parallelStream() {
            delegateList.stream()
        }
    }
```

So in the the OP's example, they'd change the mocking of getPlanConfigConstraintValidators to look like this:

```
        getPlanConfigConstraintValidators() >> new NoParallelStreamsList(
                delegateList: [
                    Mock(PlanConfigConstraintValidator),
                    Mock(PlanConfigConstraintValidator),
                ]
        )
```